# delete duplicate rows has null

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the data

```
Id Name Value col1 col2 col3
1  test1 1    null null null
2  test1 1    x    null null
3  test1 1    x    y    null
4  test2 2    x    y    z
5  test2 2    x    y    null
```

Find duplicate based on "Name" and "Value" column and delete the one which has null values in more columns.

I managed to delete duplicates by following http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_delete_duplicate_table_rows.htm#null but dint know what should be done to achieve this in SQL

Expected result

```
ID Name Value col1 Col2 Col3
3  test1  1   X     y    null
4  test2  2   x     y    z
```

Comment: Are there three columns? Or is this just an example?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem there were many more than 10, i have put 3 just for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Id, Name, Value, col1, col2, col3 ) AS
SELECT 1,  'test1', 1,    null, null, null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,  'test1', 1,    'x',  null, null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,  'test1', 1,    'x',  'y',  null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,  'test2', 2,    'x',  'y',  'z'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,  'test2', 2,    'x',  'y',  null FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY name, value
           ORDER BY DECODE( col1, NULL, 0, 1 )
                      + DECODE( col2, NULL, 0, 1 )
                      + DECODE( col3, NULL, 0, 1 ) DESC,
                    col1, col2, col3
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

**Output**:

```
        ID NAME       VALUE C C C         RN
---------- ----- ---------- - - - ----------
         3 test1          1 x y            1
         4 test2          2 x y z          1
```